# How to setup calm antivirus in k8s environment and interact from a django app pod?

Tags: django, kubernetes, clam, clamav

I am using django-clamd (https://github.com/vstoykov/django-clamd) inside my django app. The scanning works fine on my local system while uploading files and virus containing files are detected.
I want to achieve the same for my app pod in kubernetes environment. Any ideas how to setup clam antivirus as a single instance(one pod per node in the cluster) in k8s so that apps deployed in different namespaces can be scanned using the clamav? I do not want to setup a separate instance of clamav for every app deloyment as a single clam av instance needs around 1 GB of RAM.

Comment: Have you looked at `Daemonset`? They work by scheduling a pod per node if that's what you want.

Comment: Are deploying app in different namespaces? It won't be possible to deploy one instance to cover all namespaces.

Comment: Hi @MariuszK. Yes i am deploying app in different namespaces. What could be the other way around to implement the antivirus?